# Foursquare API Rate limit reset

Tags: foursquare

If I make a Foursquare API (Venue Details API) call say exactly at 12:00 PM and consume all the hourly rate limit by 12:15 PM then when does Foursquare will refresh the rate limit again so that I can make calls in the next call ?

In other words if my API call limit is 500 at 12:00 PM then will it be reset again at 01:00 PM.

How does FourSquare maintain the hourly limit of an API. Is the window fixed i.e. 12.00 pm to 1.00 PM then 1.00 PM to 2.00 pm or so or it maintains the hour from the first API call ?

Comment: Cute. The Foursquare forum links back here. Anyway, check out https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits . If you *really* need the answer, I suggest you do your own experiments and examine the returned HTTP headers. But like they say, 500 ought to be enough for everyone and if it isn't you can apply for more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! But I have a scheduled process that will trigger at every hour and stops when the rate limit exceeds. And as you suggested to do experiments but I got mixed results so wanted the confirmation on this.

Answer (score 1):

The rate limit window is rolling (i.e. it doesn't use fixed hourly buckets)